# PayPal Sandbox API Status

Tags: php, api, paypal

Im having issues with the paypal sandbox api today. It seems that Im getting no return data back from PayPal. None of the code has changed and it was tested and working last night.

I am using the Angeleye classic API library. https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/

In my code I am using their adaptive payment API.

The errors Im getting are

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /src/angelleye/PayPal/Adaptive.php on line 1394

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /src/angelleye/PayPal/Adaptive.php on line 158

Both of those places are for PayPal Return Data.

Other than my sent data I am getting

[Errors] => Array ( ) [Ack] => [Build] => [CorrelationID] => [Timestamp] => [PreapprovalKey] => [RedirectURL] => [XMLRequest] =>

and at the end I have [XMLResponse] =>

Any ideas?

Is there someone that can tell me if they changed something with the API or if PayPal is having issues with their Sandbox enviorment?

I checked their normal API status page but it doesnt seem to cover their Sandbox enviorment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known vulnerability with SSLv3](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A), and as such, PayPal has officially killed it on their sandbox.  They just sent out notice about an hour ago that it will officially be killed on the live servers on 12/3/14.

I've [already updated my class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) to resolve this issue, and I sent out notifications on my Facebook page, Google Page, and email newsletter.  You need to get on one of those so you can get updates like this in the future.

You need to make sure your cURL version supports TLS in order for the update to work for you.  Check phpinfo() on your server, and then look for the cURL version.  It needs to be 7.36.0.  If it's anything lower you'll probably  have to update that, too.

This is something that PayPal, eBay, Google, Facebook, etc. are all doing because of the vulnerability, so while it might be a pain if you have to update PHP/cURL on your server, it's a must.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Would never have figured that out without your answer.